# How to use formik setFieldValue in useEffect Hooks.This will create an infinite loop

Tags: reactjs, loops, react-hooks, formik

I need to use setFieldValue to put data into formik after requesting api, so I use useEffect hooks, but if I pass in the formik I defined in the second parameter, it will cause an infinite loop. If I don't pass it, a warning will be generated， This is Not allowed. so how should I fix it.

```
import {
  useGetMemberFunctionalityWithLimitMutation,
} from '../../../../redux/services/employeeManagement/employeeManagementApi';
function A1_EmployeeList() {
const [getMemberFunctionalityWithLimit] = useGetMemberFunctionalityWithLimitMutation();
 const [paginationObj, setPaginationObj] = useState({
    page: 1,
    pageSize: 10,
    employeeListQuery: {
      employerUuid,
      fullnameOrId: '',
      payrollGroupUuid: '',
      schemeUuid: '',
    },
  });
const searchFormSubmit = (values) => {
    const { fullnameOrId, payrollGroupUuid, schemeUuid } = values;
    const employeeListQuery = {
      ...paginationObj.employeeListQuery,
      fullnameOrId: fullnameOrId ? fullnameOrId : '',
      payrollGroupUuid: schemeUuid ? payrollGroupUuid : '',
      schemeUuid: schemeUuid ? schemeUuid : '',
    };
    setPaginationObj({
      ...paginationObj,
      page: 1,
      employeeListQuery,
    });
  };

const formik = useFormik({
    initialValues: {
      fullnameOrId: '',
      schemeUuid: '',
      payrollGroupUuid: '',
      dataList: [],
    },
    onSubmit: (values) => {
      searchFormSubmit(values);
    },
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    const { employeeListQuery, pageSize, page } = paginationObj;
    getMemberFunctionalityWithLimit({
      page,
      limit: pageSize,
      employeeListQuery,
    })
      .unwrap()
      .then(({ payload }) => {
        formik.setFieldValue('dataList', payload.employeeList);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  }, [formik, getMemberFunctionalityWithLimit, paginationObj]);

return()
}
```

Haven't tried anything yet

Comment: Can you share the code for `paginationObj` as well?

Comment: **const [paginationObj, setPaginationObj] = useState({
    page: 1,
    pageSize: 10,
    employeeListQuery: {
      employerUuid,
      fullnameOrId: '',
      payrollGroupUuid: '',
      schemeUuid: '',
    },
  });** this is a state

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by referring to an answer, although I can't see his answer now. I added a variable to judge whether to execute this logic to prevent it from falling into a loop

```
const [getMemberFunctionalityWithLimit] = useGetMemberFunctionalityWithLimitMutation();
const [paginationObj, setPaginationObj] = useState({
    page: 1,
    pageSize: 10,
    employeeListQuery: {
      employerUuid,
      fullnameOrId: '',
      payrollGroupUuid: '',
      schemeUuid: '',
    },
  });

const flag = useRef(true);

const searchFormSubmit = (values) => {
    const { fullnameOrId, payrollGroupUuid, schemeUuid } = values;
    const employeeListQuery = {
      ...paginationObj.employeeListQuery,
      fullnameOrId: fullnameOrId ? fullnameOrId : '',
      payrollGroupUuid: schemeUuid ? payrollGroupUuid : '',
      schemeUuid: schemeUuid ? schemeUuid : '',
    };
    flag.current = true;
    setPaginationObj({
      ...paginationObj,
      page: 1,
      employeeListQuery,
    });
  };

const formik = useFormik({
    initialValues: {
      fullnameOrId: '',
      schemeUuid: '',
      payrollGroupUuid: '',
      dataList: [],
    },
    onSubmit: (values) => {
      searchFormSubmit(values);
    },
  });

  useEffect(() => {
  if (flag.current) {
    flag.current = false;
    const { employeeListQuery, pageSize, page } = paginationObj;
    getMemberFunctionalityWithLimit({
      page,
      limit: pageSize,
      employeeListQuery,
    })
      .unwrap()
      .then(({ payload }) => {
        formik.setFieldValue('dataList', payload.employeeList);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  }
  }, [formik, getMemberFunctionalityWithLimit, paginationObj, flag]);
```